# Error: Column `` is of unsupported type NULL

Tags: r

```
structure(list(Date = c("2019.01.26", "2019.01.26", "2019.01.26", 
"2019.01.26", "2019.01.26", "2019.01.26", "2019.01.26", "2019.01.26", 
"2019.01.26", "2019.01.26", "2019.01.26", "2019.01.26", "2019.01.26", 
"2019.01.26", "2019.01.26", "2019.01.26", "2019.01.26", "2019.01.26", 
"2019.01.26", "2019.01.26"), Participant = c("CV", "CV", "CV", 
"CV", "CV", "CV", "CV", "CV", "CV", "CV", "CV", "CV", "CV", "CV", 
"CV", "CV", "CV", "CV", "CV", "CV"), Machine_ASVZ = c("A1", "A1", 
"A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", 
"A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1"), Machine = c("LEG PRESS", 
"LEG PRESS", "LEG PRESS", "LEG PRESS", "LEG PRESS", "LEG PRESS", 
"LEG PRESS", "LEG PRESS", "LEG PRESS", "LEG PRESS", "LEG PRESS", 
"LEG PRESS", "LEG PRESS", "LEG PRESS", "LEG PRESS", "LEG PRESS", 
"LEG PRESS", "LEG PRESS", "LEG PRESS", "LEG PRESS"), Set = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Contraction_Mode = c("Con01", 
"Con02", "Con03", "Con04", "Con05", "Con06", "Con07", "Con08", 
"Con09", "Con10", "Con01", "Con02", "Con03", "Con04", "Con05", 
"Con06", "Con07", "Con08", "Con09", "Con10"), Time_Video_CV = c(1340, 
1160, 1220, 1260, 1560, 1020, 1060, 1100, 1060, 1040, 1080, 980, 
1020, 1000, 940, 1000, 960, 1000, 900, 980), Time_Video_GRFD = c(1360, 
1180, 1240, 1280, 1180, 1060, 1080, 1100, 1060, 1060, 1100, 980, 
1020, 1020, 980, 1020, 960, 980, 920, 1040), Time_Smartphone_1 = c(1650, 
1350, 1400, 1400, 1350, 1250, 1550, 1500, 1600, 1650, 2500, 1100, 
1100, 1150, 1100, 1200, 1350, 1450, 1200, 1600), Time_Smartphone_3 = c(1700, 
1350, 1350, 1350, 1300, 1250, 1600, 1500, 1650, 1650, 1300, 1100, 
1150, 1150, 1100, 1150, 1200, 1400, 1400, 1700), Rater_Mean = c(1350, 
1170, 1230, 1270, 1370, 1040, 1070, 1100, 1060, 1050, 1090, 980, 
1020, 1010, 960, 1010, 960, 990, 910, 1010), Smartphone_Mean = c(1675, 
1350, 1375, 1375, 1325, 1250, 1575, 1500, 1625, 1650, 1900, 1100, 
1125, 1150, 1100, 1175, 1275, 1425, 1300, 1650), Relative_Diff = c(0.241, 
0.154, 0.118, 0.083, 0.033, 0.202, 0.472, 0.364, 0.533, 0.571, 
0.743, 0.122, 0.103, 0.139, 0.146, 0.163, 0.328, 0.439, 0.429, 
0.634), RaterSmartphone_Diff = c(-325, -180, -145, -105, 45, 
-210, -505, -400, -565, -600, -810, -120, -105, -140, -140, -165, 
-315, -435, -390, -640), RaterSmartphone_Mean = c(1512.5, 1260, 
1302.5, 1322.5, 1347.5, 1145, 1322.5, 1300, 1342.5, 1350, 1495, 
1040, 1072.5, 1080, 1030, 1092.5, 1117.5, 1207.5, 1105, 1330), 
    Contraction_Mode_Levels = c("Con", "Con", "Con", "Con", "Con", 
    "Con", "Con", "Con", "Con", "Con", "Con", "Con", "Con", "Con", 
    "Con", "Con", "Con", "Con", "Con", "Con"), Rater_Diff = c(-20, 
    -20, -20, -20, 380, -40, -20, 0, 0, -20, -20, 0, 0, -20, 
    -40, -20, 0, 20, -20, -60), Smartphone_Diff = c(-50, 0, 50, 
    50, 50, 0, -50, 0, -50, 0, 1200, 0, -50, 0, 0, 50, 150, 50, 
    -200, -100), RaterSmartphone_Diff_Potential_Outlier = c(FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE), Rater_Diff_Potential_Outlier = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), 
    Smartphone_Diff_Potential_Outlier = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), Normalized_Error_Smartphone = c(19.4, 
    13.33, 10.55, 7.64, 3.4, 16.8, 32.06, 26.67, 34.77, 36.36, 
    42.63, 10.91, 9.33, 12.17, 12.73, 14.04, 24.71, 30.53, 30, 
    38.79), Participant_Age_Levels = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("old", "young"), class = "factor"), Participant_Age = c(42, 
    42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 
    42, 42, 42, 42)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Above you can find an exert of my data.frame. I try to group the data by Machine and Contraction_Mode_Levels and then to summarise a Mann-Withney-U test for both of the two factors "young" ang "old".

I am trying to run a Mann-Withney-U test as the follwing:

```
wilcox<-all_data_wide_outlier_levels %>% 
  group_by(Machine,Contraction_Mode_Levels) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(wilcox.test(.[Participant_Age_Levels == "young"], 
                                  .[Participant_Age_Levels == "old"],
                                  paired=FALSE, alternative = c("two.sided"))$parameter,
                      wilcox.test(.[Participant_Age_Levels == "young"], 
                                  .[Participant_Age_Levels == "old"],
                                  paired=FALSE, alternative = c("two.sided"))$statistic,
                      wilcox.test(.[Participant_Age_Levels == "young"], 
                                  .[Participant_Age_Levels == "old"],
                                  paired=FALSE, alternative = c("two.sided"))$p.value),
                 vars = Rater_Mean)
```

Which throws back a error:

> Error: Column `vars_$..1` is of unsupported type NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there was only your data with one level, I use an example below to show how to use broom to get the statistic you need:

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(
Machine = sample(c("LEG PRESS","Y PRESS"),100,replace=TRUE),
Contraction_Mode_Levels = sample(c("Con01","Con02","Con03"),100,replace=TRUE),
Rater_Mean = runif(100),
Participant_Age_Levels = sample(c("young","old"),100,replace=TRUE))

df %>% group_by(Machine,Contraction_Mode_Levels) %>% do(tidy(wilcox.test(Rater_Mean ~  Participant_Age_Levels,data=. )))

# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   Machine, Contraction_Mode_Levels [6]
  Machine   Contraction_Mode_Lev… statistic p.value method           alternative
  <fct>     <fct>                     <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>            <chr>      
1 LEG PRESS Con01                        22   0.607 Wilcoxon rank s… two.sided  
2 LEG PRESS Con02                        45   0.730 Wilcoxon rank s… two.sided  
3 LEG PRESS Con03                        22   0.607 Wilcoxon rank s… two.sided  
4 Y PRESS   Con01                        38   0.604 Wilcoxon rank s… two.sided  
5 Y PRESS   Con02                        33   0.613 Wilcoxon rank s… two.sided  
6 Y PRESS   Con03                        45   0.696 Wilcoxon rank s… two.sided
```

From your code, I guess you are only interested in the difference in Rater_Mean between "young" and "old" groups in Participant_Age_Levels, hence you can write `wilcox.test(Rater_Mean ~ Participant_Age_Levels)` .

Comment: awesome, you saved my day! Thanks a lot. Never heard of broom. Was struggling multiple hours with my approach.

Comment: Hey, glad it worked for you :) Do check out the vignette for more uses of it https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html